# git branch of a pushed commit changes to another branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, gitlab

I already pushed a commit to a remote branch. There is any way to change that commit pushed to another remote branch.

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

can I use the cherry pick for copying the commit to another branch?

Comment: Does the answer helps you solve the problem? If yes, can you mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer? And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really pushed to the wrong remote branch, then you probably have to first undo that push, at least logically, and then do a second push to the correct branch.  So something like this:

```
# undo first commit to wrong branch2
git checkout branch2
git pull origin branch2
git revert <SHA-1 of commit from branch1>
git push origin branch2

# now push to correct branch
git checkout branch1
git push origin branch1
```

I used `git revert` to undo your unwanted commit to `branch2`, assuming that this branch is already publicly shared.  Reverting a commit is the safe way to proceed in this situation.